# How to get an in-between slicer to only show values which are filter in Date Table rather than MIN/MAX of Date Table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a Date Table (Thanks to Sam Nseir!) in place and my Fiscal Month is from 21-22 each month.

When I select a fiscal month these are the values I get in this format dd/MM (This is a calculated column on the Date column marked in Date Table.
This is for March selection.

[image]

I want to make this as an in-between slicer but when I use the Date column marked in Date Table in the slicer the date range it shows always lies in the range of `MIN(DateTable[Date])` and `MAX(DateTable[Date])`

[image]

How can I make an in-between slicer so that when I select March I get a slicer with a range of values shown above that is 22 February to 21 March?

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: Sure. Give me a sec.

Comment: I'll answer now

Comment: Thank you! I want this confidence someday to say, "I'll answer now."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it already works for me. If you go to edit interactions on the ribbon and change it to filter the visual, you get the desired behaviour don't you?

[image]

[image]